# Why does the order of imports in python messes up functions in the imports of the imports?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have the following scenario [the structure of the files is provided below].

I have a script `script.py` which contains a function which I call to render an image. The renderer uses some calls to some library(opendr).

I discovered after not little frustration that if the imports in my script function were in a certain order, then my rendered image would be completely black, yet arranged in a different way the rendering would be just fine.

After shuffling around with the imports, I discovered the two problematic imports in `script.py`: *data_paths.data_paths* and *render.render*. I have dug further and discovered the problematic imports in the two files: **PI1** in `render.py` and **PI2** in `data_paths.py`. if PI1 is imported before PI2, it works, otherwise it doesn't. I have even tried importing PI1 then `data_paths.py` (which imports PI2), then `render.py` (which imports PI1) and it works. The only thing which seems to be important is importing PI1 before PI2, no matter the file where it is imported.

Now PI1 is an external library call so there's nothing I can do about it, while PI2 is an internal library call. So I investigated even further. If I copy the function imported by PI2 into `data_paths.py`, the rendering works (same name, or a different name - it doesn't matter).
If I comment all other functions defined in `utils.py` but the function imported by PI2 and another function needed in `script.py`, it doesn't work.

I do not understand why I have this behavior and how I can make sure I won't have this bug again, since I will be using the functions in `render.py` quite a lot, and I don't want to always shuffle my imports around and never be sure if it will work or not.

I got that the order of imports in the `script.py` matters, but I don't understand why it would affect functions imported by the imports. I also don't get why moving the function `get_machine.py` to `data_paths.py` helps, but commenting everything redundant in the original file doesn't.

I am sorry I cannot offer a proper demo, it is quite a lot of code under a license and a whole library to install.

```
# script.py
from data_paths import data_paths
from render import render

def main():
  render()
```

This is how render.py lools like

```
# render.py
from opendr.renderer import ColoredRenderer # problematic import 1
# ... other imports

def render():
  # function body
```

This is how data_paths.py looks like

```
# data_paths.py
from utils import get_machine # problematic import 2

if get_machine=='whatever':
  RANDOM_GLOBAL_VARIABLE1 = 'value1'
else:
  RANDOM_GLOBAL_VARIABLE1 = 'value2'

ANOTHER_GLOBAL_VARIABLE1 = 1
ANOTHER_GLOBAL_VARIABLE2 = 1

class data_paths:
  a bunch of functions
```

And, finally, utils.py:

```
# utils.py
def get_machine():
  # function body

def needed_function():
  # function body

def not_needed_function1():
  # function body

def not_needed_function2():
  # function body
```

Comment: This sounds like either a circular import problem or a name collision, but we can't tell what it is from what you've shown us. You may not be able to post your entire real project (and we wouldn't want to read your entire real project), but you should be able to construct a [mcve] that's much smaller and doesn't involve proprietary code or external libraries.

Comment: Is there some way you can make a simplified version of your code that still has the problem? Obviously there's something in `PI2` that depends on `PI1`, but it's hard to tell from what you've posted.

Comment: I am trying, but it is very very time consuming to do such an example. A circular import cannot be since PI1 and PI2 don't import each other. I find it hard to believe it's a name clash either, since, again, they don't import each other. Could it be related to the PYTHONPATH variable? I just don't really know where to look before I have to go through an insane amount of work tearing everything apart.